# Force Google Chrome to use POST from OpenSearch.xml

Tags: html, xml, google-chrome, search, server

I run the website DuckDuckStart, which attempts to utilize an OpenSearch standard XML file to allow browsers to discover it and use the website as a default search engine for browsers. (I personally use this in Firefox and Chrome.) (I've tested it even again with the most recent Chrome: Version 59.0.3071.86 (Official Build) (64-bit))

However, even with forcing the **method** in the **url** parameter to **POST** Google Chrome always sends a *GET* request to the server rather than a *POST*

Is there a way to **force** Chrome to use a POST method when submitting text via the omnibox (address bar)?

Here is the current iteration of my [opensearch.xml](https://duckduckstart.com/opensearch.xml) file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OpenSearchDescription xmlns="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/" xmlns:moz="http://www.mozilla.org/2006/browser/search/">
    <ShortName>DuckDuckStart</ShortName>
    <LongName>DuckDuckStart Web Search</LongName>
    <Description>DuckDuckStart passes !bang's to DuckDuckGo and everything else to Startpage</Description>
    <InputEncoding>UTF-8</InputEncoding>
    <OutputEncoding>UTF-8</OutputEncoding>
    <AdultContent>false</AdultContent>
    <Language>en-us</Language>
    <Developer>Michael Yanovich</Developer>
    <Contact>webmaster@duckduckstart.com</Contact>
    <Tags>duckduckgo startpage search</Tags>
    <Attribution>DuckDuckGo and Startpage</Attribution>
    <SyndicationRight>open</SyndicationRight>
    <Query role="example" searchTerms="Apple !i"/>
    <Image height="16" width="16" type="image/x-icon">https://duckduckstart.com/favicon.ico</Image>
    <Url type="text/html" rel="results" template="https://duckduckstart.com/" method="POST">
        <Param name="query" value="{searchTerms}" method="POST"/>
    </Url>
    <Url type="application/opensearchdescription+xml" rel="self" template="https://duckduckstart.com/opensearch.xml"/>
</OpenSearchDescription>
```

Any ideas?

I've tried using several different `<URL>` parameters that utilize the *POST*
 method, however none of the alternatives have worked.

I've read through the [OpenSearch Standard](http://www.opensearch.org/Specifications/OpenSearch/Extensions/Parameter/1.0/Draft_2#The_.22Url.22_element) and have attempted several other examples across the internet. Most of the examples utilize the *GET* method, but the few that cover the *POST* method don't work and haven't worked. I've been casually testing this in ever Chrome version since about Chrome 39.

PS: The back up method I've been using, which defeats the purpose of the site, is to configure Chrome manually to point to https://duckduckstart.com/?query=%s in the "Add Other Search Engines" in the settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like that at the moment that it is a documented "bug" in Chromium and hasn't been touch in a while.

Looks like nobody is actively working on it. :-(

https://crbug.com/18107

Comment: I have a Jenkins setup in my local network. When I look at the access log it shows me Jenkins gave 403 response to /opensearch.xml request.

10.20.2.20 - - [06/Jan/2024:07:11:16 +0000] "GET /opensearch.xml HTTP/1.1" 403 1064 "-" "<Removing browser footprint for security>"